# How to insert line break in a return statement for D3

Tags: d3.js, line-breaks

I have the following code d3 code:

```
tooltip.select("#popupCount").text(function(){

if (varToGraph == "rough_top_cost"){
return " " + textValue + ": $" + addCommas(allCountyData[countyName][varToGraph]) + "\n" +
"Count:"
}})
```

I want the word count to appear on a new line. However, the above code results in everything being on one line. How can I get the output to be on two  lines?

Thanks,
AH

Comment: Are you creating an SVG? You can't have line breaks in SVG text elements unfortunately. You could have two separate text elements or use an HTML div via SVG's foreignObject element.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I can have another statement such as tooltip.select("#popupCount").text(.....)?

Comment: No, that would overwrite the other text. You'll need another element.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to D3 and do not understand what you mean by element. Do you mean instead of doing tooltip.select("popupCount") I should do tooltip.select("popupCount1"), with popupCount1 being the new element?

Comment: Yes. You are probably better off using foreignObject though.

Answer (score 0):

Untested answer, but FWIW this may get close;

```
tooltip.select("#popupCount").html(function(){
if (varToGraph == "rough_top_cost"){
return " " + textValue + ": <br/>$" + addCommas(allCountyData[countyName][varToGraph]) + "\n" +
"Count:"
}})
```

Working from the example provided on page 80 of [D3 Tips and Tricks](http://www.d3noob.org/p/d3noob-downloads.html) which includes tooltips with line breaks.

Uses html element instead of text which allows line breaks. Check out the document for more detail.